# Python socket: How can a client send multiple messages to server

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

***Very new to coding***. I have these two Python scripts. One is a **server** and the other is the **GUI** which also acts as a client (because I didn't know how to connect them otherwise as I needed to send the data produced by the GUI to the server). In the while loop you can see that I'm receiving messages from all three connections.
**user 1 is conn

user 2 is conn1

GUI is conn2**

but from both user 1 and user 2 they are sending one message each (*which is the dBA going through the mic at a given moment*). But for the GUI it's sending three messages (*Audio-Threshold, first mic index, second mic index*) that I need to receive at the server side. But this way shown in the server does not seem to work as I'm receiving these messages but in a weird/different pattern every time I run the code.

***Server Side:***

```
import socket
import requests
import os

PARAMS = {'Function': "Cut",
          "Duration": 300,          # First Camera
          "Input": 1}
PARAMS2 = {'Function': "Cut",
           "Duration": 300,         # Second Camera
           "Input": 2}
PARAMS3 = {'Function': "Cut",
           "Duration": 300,         # Overview Camera
           "Input": 3}


# VMix's API Endpoint - Requests are made to this API
URL_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/"

CLIENT1 = "Client 1"
CLIENT2 = "Client 2"
TH = "Threshold"
INDEX1 = "INDEX1"
INDEX2 = "INDEX2"


# Socket creation
s = socket.socket()  # Creates a socket
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 50200
print("Socket Created...")
s.bind((host, port))
print("Socket Bound...")
s.listen()
print("Waiting for connections...")
print(26 * '-')

# GUI client
conn2, addr2 = s.accept()
print(f"☑ GUI with IP: {addr2} has connected...")

# Setup the connection for the first client
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(f"☑ Client with address {addr} has connected...")


# Connection setup for the second client
conn1, addr1 = s.accept()
print(f"☑ Client with address {addr} has connected...")

print(26 * '-')

print("Recieving audio")

while True:
    print("{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}{}".format(CLIENT1, CLIENT2, TH, INDEX1, INDEX2))
    while 1:
        recv_message, recv_message1, recv_message2 = conn.recv(128), conn1.recv(128), conn2.recv(1024)
        recv_index, recv_index1 = conn2.recv(1024), conn2.recv(1024)

        print("{:18}{:18}{:18}{:18}{}".format(recv_message.decode(
            "utf-8"), recv_message1.decode("utf-8"), recv_message2.decode("utf-8"),
            recv_index.decode("utf-8"), recv_index1.decode("utf-8")))

        threshold = recv_message2


        db, db1, threshold = int(recv_message), int(recv_message1), int(threshold)
        if (db > threshold) and (db > db1):
            response = requests.get(url=URL_ENDPOINT, params=PARAMS)
        elif (db1 > threshold) and (db1 > db):
            response = requests.get(url=URL_ENDPOINT, params=PARAMS2)
        else:
            response = requests.get(url=URL_ENDPOINT, params=PARAMS3)
```

**GUI Side:**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import subprocess
import requests
import socket
import struct
import os
import time
from threading import *
try:
    import pyaudio
except ImportError:
    os = struct.calcsize("P") * 8
    if(os == 32):
        url = 'https://kenan0x0.github.io/Project-PAD/week3/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl'
        local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        open(local_filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
        subprocess.call(["pip", "install", local_filename], shell=False)
        subprocess.call(
            ["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "pyaudio"], shell=False)
    else:
        url1 = 'https://kenan0x0.github.io/Project-PAD/week3/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'
        local_filename1 = url1.split('/')[-1]
        r1 = requests.get(url1, allow_redirects=True)
        open(local_filename1, 'wb').write(r1.content)
        subprocess.call(["pip", "install", local_filename1], shell=False)
        subprocess.call(
            ["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "pyaudio"], shell=False)


s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 50200
s.connect((host, port))

# Main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("650x600")
window.title("Black Magic Switcher")
window.iconbitmap(r'./Iconshock-Disc-Jockey-Mixer.ico')

# Threads so functions can be called simultaneously


def cliThread():

    Thread(target=runClient).start()


def klaThread():
    Thread(target=runClient2).start()


def devThread():
    Thread(target=showDevi).start()

# ------------------ End Threads ----------------------

# Functions that perform a task


def showTH():
    # while True:
    #     s.send(val.encode("utf-8"))
    #     time.sleep(0.2)
    #     window.update()
    while True:
        threshold = ThresholdEntry.get()
        threshold = str(threshold)
        s.send(threshold.encode("utf-8"))
        time.sleep(0.2)
        window.update()
# Runs Client 1


def runClient():
    os.system("python client.py")

# Runs Client 2


def runClient2():
    os.system("python klant.py")


# Prints entry values first mic


def showEntry():
    index = firstMicEntry.get()
    index = str(index)
    s.send(index.encode("utf-8"))

# Prints entry values second mic


def showEntry1():
    index = secondMicEntry.get()
    index = str(index)
    s.send(index.encode("utf-8"))

# Shows connected input devices


def showDevi():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
    numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
    for i in range(0, numdevices):
        if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
            lbl = tk.Label(text=("Input Device id ", i, " - ",
                                 p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name')))
            lbl.pack()


def killServer():
    os.system("taskkill /f /im py.exe")

# ----------------------- End Functions -----------------------------


# Title of the program
h1 = tk.Label(text="User GUI | Black Magic", font=("Kreon", 25))
h1.pack()

bk1 = ttk.Separator(window, orient="horizontal")
bk1.pack(fill="x", pady=5)

# Threshold
h2 = tk.Label(text="Audio-Threshold: ⤵", font=("Kreon", 15))
h2.pack()


# scale = tk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=100, command=showTH,
#                  orient="horizontal", length=400, cursor="fleur")
# scale.set(44)
# scale.pack(pady=3)

ThresholdEntry = tk.Entry(width=20, justify="center", bd=3)
ThresholdEntry.pack(pady=3)
sendTH = tk.Button(text="Input Threshold", activebackground="black",
                   activeforeground="white", cursor="hand2", relief="raised", command=showTH)
sendTH.pack(pady=3)

# Devices listing Button
devbut = tk.Button(text="Show Available Mics", activebackground="black",
                   activeforeground="white", cursor="hand2", relief="raised",
                   command=devThread)
devbut.pack(pady=3)


# Label change first mic
firstMic = tk.Label(text="Insert First Mic Index ⤵: ")
firstMic.pack(pady=3)
firstMicEntry = tk.Entry(width=20, justify="center", bd=3)
firstMicEntry.pack(pady=3)
sendMicIndex = tk.Button(text="Send First Index", activebackground="black",
                         activeforeground="white", cursor="hand2", relief="raised", command=showEntry)
sendMicIndex.pack(pady=3)

# Client 1 Button
clibut = tk.Button(text="Run First Client", activebackground="black",
                   activeforeground="white", cursor="hand2", relief="raised", command=cliThread)
clibut.pack(pady=3)


# Label change second mic
secondMic = tk.Label(text="Insert Second Mic Index ⤵: ")
secondMic.pack(pady=3)
secondMicEntry = tk.Entry(width=20, justify="center", bd=3)
secondMicEntry.pack(pady=3)
sendMicIndex1 = tk.Button(text="Send Second Index", activebackground="black",
                          activeforeground="white", cursor="hand2", relief="raised", command=showEntry1)
sendMicIndex1.pack(pady=3)

# Client 2 Button
klabut = tk.Button(text="Run Second Client", activebackground="black",
                   activeforeground="white", cursor="hand2", relief="raised", command=klaThread)
klabut.pack(pady=3)

exitBut = tk.Button(text="Stop Program", activebackground="black",
                    activeforeground="white", cursor="hand2", relief="raised", command=killServer)
exitBut.pack(pady=3)

window.mainloop()
```

After all this code my question is. Is it possible for the client to use multiple `socket.send()` statements and for the server to receive them with the same number of `connection.recv()` statements in the correct order.
I know that there are like a million things that need to be improved in this code but for a beginner's code, it's doing what I need it to do except for these multiple sends. If you have other notes on the code please do share them.

Comment: What you could do is send a _name_ together with the actual message. So instead of sending `index.encode("utf-8")`, you could send `("audio-threshold: " + index).encode("utf-8")`, and decode that message on the server.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. The reason is that as you can see, after the values reach the server they are then casted back to (int) and then used in the else-if statement. I'll try that anyway and if it works I can substring it.

Comment: Exactly, first check whether the string `startswith` your special code, and then cast the substring.

Comment: I've just tried that, didn't work :( As I mentioned above, when I receive multiple messages from the same connection they're for some reason being mixed up. So variable that should hold the threshold is getting the index and vice versa.
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 78, in <module>
    db, db1, threshold = int(recv_message), int(recv_message1), int(threshold)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020first index is 10202020202020202020202020202020'```

Comment: Try to manually check whether the received string is exactly as you sent it. It looks like multiple messages are received as a single message.

Comment: That's the way TCP works.  You don't send a "message", you send bytes.  It is just a stream of bytes with no message boundaries.  You get the bytes in the same order but not in the same grouping of bytes as sent.  So you have to have a mechanism like terminating each message with a newline, so you know you have a complete message.

Comment: Could you maybe further explain how to do that. I've heard about something like flushing the socket to empty the buffer (Not sure).